# How can I disable Audio Playback in Android Chrome when the process is Backgrounded?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

How can I programmatically disable a song from playing in the background of a Chrome Android process?

Here's a simple example of a page which plays a song in Chrome:

https://thomashunter.name/examples/chrome-audio-bug.html

```
var song = new Audio('song.ogg');
song.loop = 'loop';

button = document.getElementById('play');

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  song.play();
});
```

Notice how the song will keep playing in the background. While nice for a jukebox, it'll drive a player of a web game insane.

Is there a way to disable background playing of a single `Audio` element in Chrome? Or, is there at least a callback for when the page loses focus so I could run `song.stop()`?

Comment: You say the `blur` event does not fire. Does `document.hasFocus()` change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `visibilitychange`:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(){
    if (document.hidden) {
        // Document is hidden 

        // This re-initialize the audio element
        // to release the audio focus
        song.load(); 
    }
    else {
        // Document is focused
    }
},false);
```

The complete example is available here https://jsfiddle.net/6001wsf9/

Tested on Android 5.0 with Chrome 43.0.2357.78

Comment: Worked like a charm! Also, surprisingly, I'm able to execute song.play() in the else clause. Apparently the `visibilitychange` event is categorized as human interaction in Android Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5 Visibility API

```js
    <script>
    var song = new Audio('http://zyu.me:1337/audio/Evasion.ogg');
    song.loop = 'loop';

    button = document.getElementById('play');

    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      song.play();
    });
var vis = (function(){
    var stateKey, 
        eventKey, 
        keys = {
                hidden: "visibilitychange",
                webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
                mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
                msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
    };
    for (stateKey in keys) {
        if (stateKey in document) {
            eventKey = keys[stateKey];
            break;
        }
    }
    return function(c) {
        if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
        return !document[stateKey];
    }
})();
  
  vis(function(){
     
    if(vis()){
        console.log("tab is visible");
  song.play();         
    } else {
 
        console.log("tab is invisible"); 
  song.pause();
    }
});
  
  
  </script>
```

Comment: For more info on this and other specific use cases see http://greensock.com/forums/topic/9059-cross-browser-to-detect-tab-or-window-is-active-so-animations-stay-in-sync-using-html5-visibility-api/